# How do I change "Open" to "Select" in the NSOpenPanel?

Tags: cocoa, macos, objective-c++, nsopenpanel

In my Application i need to show the select file dialog, 
I am making use of the NSOpenPanel which allows to select the file, code is as shown below,

```
- (IBAction)sendFileButtonAction:(id)sender{

    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    // Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

    // Display the dialog.  If the OK button was pressed,
    // process the files.
    if ( [openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil] == NSOKButton )
    {
        // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
        // files and directories selected.
        NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];

        // Loop through all the files and process them.
        for( int i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i];
            [self log:fileName];

            // Do something with the filename.
        }
    }

}
```

everything works perfect, but i am facing only one issue, while opening the file, it shows the Open and Cancel button, 
Is there any way to rename the open button to “Select” button, or do i need to use some other Cocoa Resource.

Comment: By the way, the filenames property is declared deprecated in OS X 10.6

Comment: runModalForDirectory:file:types: is deprecated in OS X v10.6. You could use runModal instead. You can set path using setDirectoryURL:, and you can set fileTypes using setAllowedFileTypes:.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this line:

```
[openDlg setPrompt:@"Select"];
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the filename you select diplay onto a label? Or a way to Actually select the file and store it in the application to access it later? Thanks!!

Comment: I suppose yes, in the framework you would get callback, delegate for the selected file name and that you could use to display it over the label

Comment: hey i want to close openPanel on tapping select can you tell me hows it possible @Anne

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot for the question and answers. I have replaced deprecated methods and it seems to work fine. Sorry not yet sure about editing other people answers (new to contributing here).

```
 - (IBAction)sendFileButtonAction:(id)sender{

    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    // Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

    // Change "Open" dialog button to "Select"
    [openDlg setPrompt:@"Select"];

    // Display the dialog.  If the OK button was pressed,
    // process the files.
    if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSModalResponseOK )
    {
        // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
        // files and directories selected.
        NSArray* files = [openDlg URLs];

        // Loop through all the files and process them.
        for( int i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"file: %@", fileName);
            // Do something with the filename.
        }
    }
}
```